# Covering sets in a ring by a disjoint union of sets in a ring.

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, measure-theory

$\newcommand{\scrD}{\mathcal{D}}$
A situating definition.

> **Definition:** Let $\Omega$ be a set. A **ring** $\scrD$ is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ such that $A \cup B \in \scrD$ and $A \setminus B \in \scrD$ for all $A,B \in \scrD$.

**Problem:** Let $\scrD$ be a ring of sets in an arbitrary set $\Omega$ and $E_1,\dots,E_n \in \scrD$. Show there are finitely many disjoint sets $F_1,\dots,F_m$ such that each $E_k$ is a union of some $F_j$'s.

I looked at the $n=1,2,3$ cases to get situated an I think I get the idea, it's easy to see with an image. In the case where $E_1,E_2,E_3$ are disjoint then you simply let $F_i = E_i$ and you're done, so it's only really interesting if they overlap. In the $n=2$ case, it's straightforward to see that you could pick $F_1 = E_1 \setminus E_2, F_2 = E_2 \setminus E_1$ and $F_3 = E_1 \cap E_2$. These are all disjoint and $E_1 = F_1 \cup F_3$ and $E_2 = F_2 \cup F_3$.

Similarly in the $n =3$ case you follow the same pattern and can write
\begin{align*}
F_1 & =E_1 \setminus (E_2 \cup E_3) \\
F_2 & = E_2 \setminus (E_1 \cup E_3) \\
F_3 & = E_3 \setminus (E_1 \cup E_2) \\
F_4 & = (E_1 \cap E_2) \setminus E_3 \\
F_5 & = (E_1 \cap E_3) \setminus E_2 \\
F_6 & = (E_2 \cap E_3) \setminus E_1 \\
F_7 & = E_1 \cap E_2 \cap E_3
\end{align*}
All of these are disjoint, and for example $E_3 = F_3 \cup F_5 \cup F_6 \cup F_7$. Making the decomposition in this way of course give you elements of the ring since we're just iterating unions, intersections and differences which are all valid. I put combinatorics as a tag (correct me if I'm wrong), because I imagine continuing this to the general case requires some counting argument. I've never been very good at combinatorial arguments, so I don't quite know what type of question am I should be asking here, in terms of a "how many ways are there to pick X things from Y things w/wo replacement". I suppose I'm asking precisely how would I formulate this construction as a counting argument?

Sorry if it's basic, I just find the counting arguments unintuitive, any references would be helpful.

Comment: what is $\Omega$?

Comment: Sorry @kodlu, just an arbitrary set. Edited accordingly.

Comment: It seems that by "ring" you mean a [ring of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets)? In that case, you should state which definition of that term you're using.

Comment: Sorry, @joriki, edited accordingly.